# Telerik RadAjaxManager and Mouse Events in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, telerik, radajaxmanager

Whenever I'm using Telerik's RadAjaxManager in Chrome, the events sent to any mouse events I'm using are passed as null.

For instance, the following:

```
<img id="Image1" src="image.gif" onclick="alert(event)" />
<rad:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server"> 
            <AjaxSettings> 
            </AjaxSettings> 
</rad:RadAjaxManager>
```

Alerts **null** when clicking the image. This does not happen in IE or FF.

The version of the RadAjaxManager is 1.8.5.0. I'm guessing the problem does not occur in later versions, but an upgrade is not an option at the moment. I tried Telerik's support forum, but they didn't really provide any answer.

What could cause such a problem? And how can it be dealt with?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall well, the latest version of the old Telerik ajax is 1.8.7 - I suppose you can upgrade to it free of charge since it is a minor version compared to yours. The better choice would be to use the new ajax manager as it works seamlessly with the ASP.NET AJAX framework and the AJAX toolkit controls - I can tell that from personal experience.

Dick

Comment: I'm not sure I can get the latest version for free (when I found a bug in one of their controls a few months ago, it took some effort before they sent a newer version) - But I will try. Upgrading to their Ajax controls will probably not happen soon.

I still wonder how something like this can happen in the first place, though.

Comment: Update: I received a small example from Telerik, using version 1.8.8, and the problem occurred with that version as well.
However, I upgraded from Chrome 3.0 to the 4.0 beta, and that solved the problem.